# trying to submit a view and getting 405 error

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to implement a review section in a user profile but I keep getting this 405 error when i try to submit a review even tho when i create a review in the admin panel it shows on the profile normaly. if you could help.

Thanks in advance

Code:

Model

```
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expert = models.ForeignKey(Expert, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
```

Form

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
    'rows':3,
    }))
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('content',)
```

View

```
class ExpertDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Expert

    def expert(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ReviewForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            expert = self.get_object()
            review = form.instance
            review.user = self.request.user
            review.expert = expert
            review.save()
            print ('worked')

        print ('worked')

    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        object = super().get_object(**kwargs)
        return object

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'form': ReviewForm()
        })
        return context
```

And finaly the Template

```
<h4>Leave a comment below</h4>
      <form method='POST'>
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form|crispy}}
          <br>
          <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>review</button>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <h5>Comments</h5>
      {% for review in object.reviews %}
          <div>
              <p>{{ review.content }}
              <br />
              <small>{{ review.timestamp|timesince }} ago</small>
          </div>
          <hr />
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you post the error django returns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 405 means that the *method is not allowed*. This makes sense since you did not write a `def post(request, *args, **kwargs)`, and a `DetailView` will by default only

That being said, it is probably not a good idea to implement all the logic yourself. You can let the `ModelFormMixin` already let you do most of the work:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import ModelFormMixin

class ExpertDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, ModelFormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Expert
    form_class = ReviewForm
    success_url = 'some-url'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        review = form.instance
        review.user = self.request.user
        review.expert = self.object
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Just one extra thing if you could help me with. i get expert is not defined which most likely be in the form_valid function section. if you could help me define the expert in this instance.

Comment: @Talal: ah, well that should be `self.object`.